# create two thumbnails instead of one based on code

Tags: php

i have this code which generates me a thumbnail, nw, what i need is for it to generate me two...
just to double the function, can you please show me how can i do it based on this one?

Thanks..

```
function tamano_nuevo_foto($im_or, $ancho_nv, $dir_nv) {
    $img   = imagecreatefromjpeg($im_or);
    $datos = getimagesize($im_or);
    $ancho = $datos[0];
    $alto  = $datos[1];

    if ($ancho > $ancho_nv) { //Si la imagen no lelga al máximo no la tocamos.
        $prop    = $alto / $ancho;
        $alto_nv = round($ancho_nv * $prop);
    } else {
        $ancho_nv = $ancho;
        $alto_nv  = $alto;
    }
    $im_nv    = imagecreatetruecolor($ancho_nv, $alto_nv);
    imagecopyresampled($im_nv, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $ancho_nv, $alto_nv, $ancho, $alto);
    imagejpeg($im_nv, $dir_nv);
    imagedestroy($im_nv);
}

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetPath = str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath);
    $targetFile = $targetPath . basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], '.' . $ext) . '_s.';
    tamano_nuevo_foto($tempFile, 120, $targetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $targetFile);
}
```

Comment: ... can't you just call the function twice?

Comment: shoulw i duplicate something else? i mean if i duplicate the function i will probabbly overwrite it..

Comment: What do you mean by getting two thumbnails? How are they going to be different? Different sizes? Locations?

Comment: Hey andrewsi, i just need different size thumbnail... with different name of course

Comment: Questions like this indicate that someone doesn't fully understand a requirement, or the requirement itself wasn't thought through fully.

Comment: Or that the user doesn't explain well himself because of his knowledge in english!

Comment: @Al_12 that too. If you fill out your profile (add your location) we'll be better able to determine your expected fluency in English. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just call the function twice like in this example below?

```
if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile   = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';
    $targetPath = str_replace('//', '/', $targetPath);
    $targetFile = $targetPath . basename($_FILES['Filedata']['name'], '.' . $ext) . '_s.';
    $newTargetFile = // define whatever you want to call your second copy of thumbnail here
    tamano_nuevo_foto($tempFile, 120, $targetFile);
    tamano_nuevo_foto($tempFile, 120, $newTargetFile);
    echo str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', $targetFile);
}
```

Comment: @Al_12 Does the function actually work and not exit with an error?  Because if it does work, there shouldn't be any reason you could not call the function twice.

Comment: Yes it works... well, what can i say it doesn't work if i call it twice, maybe i overwrite the file..i don't know!

Comment: Well you need to change the filename being passed to the function as I have shown with a $newTargetFile variable in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function twice, or copy the file with [`copy()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)